# using google/gtalk account from android

Tags: android, xmpp, google-talk

I'm developing a multiplayer game that is going to work by transmitting data over XMPP chats (speed is not an issue, it's a turn-based game). Right now I'm planning on using the asmack library.

Is there a way to use the gtalk credentials from android without explicitly asking the user with a login/password dialog? Any permissions I should set in the android manifest file?

Thanks

Best regards,
Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. GTalk app wont expose its user credentials specifically password to any third party app since it kills privacy of device user.

You can do head scratch may b some pulling as well to figure out to get username (even which I don't think is possible) but now in any way password.

All the best though. Let me know if you are able to do it. Sorry for bit of discouragement :|

Comment: that's what I was thinking too, I just wanted to be sure :( thanks anyway for your answer!